# how to install tensorflow version 1.12.0 with pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I need the specific tensorflow-gpu version 1.12.0 for my application as i have cuda-9 in my system. I am able to find the whl file for tensorflow cpu , but not able to locate the same for tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: [tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.12.0/#files) is available for Python 64-bit 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 for Linux, Python 64-bit 3.5 and 3.6 for w64. Not available for 32-bit Python, not available for Python 3.7. [tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.13.1/#files) is the 1st one available for Python 3.7 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

If your python version is compatible, you can also use this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax:**

```
python -m pip install --upgrade wheel-URL
```

pick `wheel-URL` from below:

**For Windows:**

Python 3.6 CPU-only            >>            https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Python 3.6 GPU support    >>            https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

**For Linux:**

Python 2.7 CPU-only           >>    https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Python 2.7 GPU support    >>            https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Python 3.6 CPU-only           >>     https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Python 3.6 GPU support    >>     https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

**macOS (CPU-only)**

Python 2.7   >>    https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py2-none-any.whl

Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6          >>    https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many answers already, I'll just add the 2 steps that helped me as [Trien Tran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55878848/13858953) didn't change my default `tensorflow` to `1.12.0` so I was in an awkward state with `tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0` but `tensorflow 2.x`

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
pip3 install tensorflow==1.12.0
```

Note `tensorflow 1.12.0` does not work with all python versions as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096094/13858953)