# TensorFlow 1.12.0 install not visible

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow>=1.6.0,<=1.12.0
So I thought I had installed 1.12.0 by downloading the zip file from github and then running the configure.py file. Then  I installed Bezel as it asked for that but for some reason in Python Tensorflow is not visible or I didn't install it correctly.
The pip install method is not working too: pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0

Is it still possible to run version 1.12.0 ?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote this thread [how to install tensorflow version 1.12.0 with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877398/how-to-install-tensorflow-version-1-12-0-with-pip)

"tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0 is available for Python 64-bit 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 for Linux, Python 64-bit 3.5 and 3.6 for w64. Not available for 32-bit Python, not available for Python 3.7. tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 is the 1st one available for Python 3.7 64-bit."

Make sure your python is the right version and bit.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I can also resolve my problem using Docker files but may come back to try this again.